# Unable to use Excelize in Visual Studio Code from Windows machine

Tags: excel, git, go

I'm very new at this, so i'm trying to use Excelize to read a file using Go, with Visual Studio Code, from a Windows machine.

I was taking as a reference [this dZone](https://dzone.com/articles/go-language-library-for-reading-and-writing-micros) page.

When i was executing following command:

```html
go get github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize/v2
```

I got the next error:

PS C:\Users\DevMouse\Documents\Go\Tarea1> go get github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize
go: missing Git command. See https://golang.org/s/gogetcmd
package github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize: exec: "git": executable file not found in %PATH%

I've already installed git.

Any idea what command can i use to be able to use Excelize on my file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `git.exe` in your `PATH`, add

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\System32
```

to your `PATH` variable, verify by

```
git version
```

If you can see like this

```
git version 2.21.0.windows.1
```

Now you can using `go get` install the Excelize and any other Go package.